# How to limit the line width to X characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

How to limit the line width to 80 characters in MySQL? For example, I tried:

```sql
line name format 80
```

Comment: The limit you are looking for is for column data storage of for selected  result?

Comment: selected result

Comment: i have already post an asnwer ..

Comment: we dont know how to use tables yet, this is the exercise: Obtain the data of Spanish customers who have purchased more than 5 units of a one-time article This consultation will be presented as follows: Line width not greater than 75 characters –

Answer (score 0):

for storage you can define the limit when create the column

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
)
```

for select  you could use  substr

```
select substr(name,1, 80)
from myTable
```

or left

```
select left(name,80)
from myTable
```

Comment: we dont know how to use tables yet, this is the exercise:                                   
Obtain the data of Spanish customers who have purchased more than 5 units of
a one-time article This consultation will be presented as follows:                                     
Line width not greater than 75 characters